# Why the property execute before dart constructor?

Tags: dart, constructor

Why the `List list = new List()` execute before the constructor HomeContent?

```
class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget{

  List list = new List();  // no matter I write this line code before or after  `HomeContent()` 
  HomeContent() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 21; i ++) {
      this.list.add("I am item $i .");
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: this.list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(this.list[index]),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you add class members has no effect on the order of execution. When constructing a new object, the class's properties are initialised before the constructor is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Dart object initialization is defined to work the way you observe.

When you write `new Foo(...)` then the language allocates space for a `Foo` object and then goes through the initialization process for the `Foo` class and all its superclasses.

The initialization of an instance of `Foo` happens as follow:

- First evaluate instance field initializers declared in `Foo` in source order.
- Then evaluate the initializer list of the `Foo` class.
- Then recursively initialize the instance as `Foo`'s superclass, as specified by the `super` invocation of the initializer list (defaults to `super()` if you write nothing).
- When done with that, execute the `Foo` constructor body.

When this process hits the `Object` class, the object is considered properly initialized, and it's made available to the constructor bodies that are executed on the way back.

As an example:

```dart
Object log(Object value) {
  print(value);
  return value;
}
class Super /* extends Object */ {
  var superField6 = log(6);
  var superField9;
  Super(this.superField5) : superField8 = log(8), superField9 = log(9) {
    log(10);
  }
  var superField7 = log(7);
  var superField8;
  var superField5;
}
class Sub extends Super {
  var subField1 = log(1);
  var subField4;
  Sub() : subField3 = log(3), subField4 = log(4), super(log(5)) {
    log(11);
  }
  var subField2 = log(2);
  var subField3;
}
main() {
  new Sub();
}
```

If you run this code, you will see the `log` calls happening in the order of their arguments.